# Checkbox inside Edittext HOW?

Tags: android, checkbox, android-edittext, evernote

I am creating a note app in android for my thesis,just want to ask how can I put check box inside EditText and how can I save it in the database keeping the format. I saw this on evernote 
I really have no clue. thanks

Comment: i didn't see check box inside edit-text in evernote, can you post screenshot of evernote / design you want

Comment: http://blog.evernote.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/android_checklist.jpg

Comment: you have to take dynamic layout for this, every time when you hit enter at that time you have to dynamically add one more custom view with checkbox & editText.

Answer (score 0):

Try overlapping your EditText with CheckBox in a RelativeLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:inputType="text"
        />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="the checkbox" />    
</RelativeLayout>
```

What exactly would you like to save into database keeping the format? In case it is just text, you should save it in column of type text. Guide on databases could be found here: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html.